# What force is more potent than love?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

*A few quotes about Love....*

> **What force is more potent than love?**
>
> - True love is selfless. It is prepared to sacrifice.
> - We are all born for love. It is the principle of existence, and its only end.
> - Do all things with love.
> - We are most alive when we're in love.
> - The most powerful weapon on earth is the human soul on fire.
> - The greatest healing therapy is friendship and love.
> - Only do what your heart tells you.
> - You can't blame gravity for falling in love.
> - You can never control who you fall in love with, even when you're in the most sad, confused time of your life.
> - If you love someone, set them free. If they come back they're yours; if they don't they never were.
> - True love doesn't happen right away; it's an ever-growing process.
> - People confuse ego, lust, insecurity with true love.
> - If no pain, then no love. If no darkness, no light. If no risk, then no reward. It's all or nothing.
> - One must not trifle with love.
> - All you need is love. But a little chocolate now and then doesn't hurt.
> - If music be the food of love, play on.
> - Familiar acts are beautiful through love.
> - Any time not spent on love is wasted.
> - They invented hugs to let people know you love them without saying anything.
> - There is always some madness in love. But there is also always some reason in madness.
> - Work like you don't need the money. Love like you've never been hurt. Dance like nobody's watching.
> - Grief is the price we pay for love.
> - Friends show their love in times of trouble, not in happiness.
> - No matter how dark the moment, love and hope are always possible.
> - Gestures, in love, are incomparably more attractive, effective and valuable than words.
> - A new command I give you: Love one another.
> - The good life is one inspired by love and guided by knowledge.
> - Faith makes all things possible... love makes all things easy.
> - Accustom yourself continually to make many acts of love, for they enkindle and melt the soul.
> - A first love is something that lasts forever in your heart. It's something that marks you.
> - If fear is the great enemy of intimacy, love is its true friend.
> - You can be rich in spirit, kindness, love and all those things that you can't put a dollar sign on.
> - Treasure the love you receive above all. It will survive long after your good health has vanished.
> - Being in love with somebody is a wonderful feeling.
> - True love stories never have endings.
> - The moment I first heard love I gave up my soul, my heart, and my eyes.
> - There is a kind of serenity in love which is almost a paradise.
> - There are never enough *I Love You*'s.
> - Man cannot live without love.
> - The way to know life is to love many things.
> - It is difficult to know at what moment love begins; it is less difficult to know that it has begun.
> - Life without love, is no life at all.
> - Life is love - enjoy it.

***Find the hidden meaning, and have a lovely day!***

**—HINTS—**

*helpfulness level -1:*

> They're all real quotes by a variety of people. If you're interested you should be able to find them all online. This won't help you at all; the quote sources aren't part of the puzzle.

*helpfulness level 0:*

> Per usual, outside the yellow isn't part of the puzzle.  Inside the yellow, other than making it clear where one quote ends and the next begins, none of the formatting is meaningful.

*helpfulness level 1:*

> ***You can always count on love*** not to live up to its expectations. —Unknown

*helpfulness level 2:*

> The title is a quote, too...

*helpfulness level 3:*

> *So with a little touch from you*
>  *And a little hug from me*
>  *We showed the world love is strong*
>  *When ....*

Comment: 4/10 puzzle. Needs more quotes. ;) Just a quick question - you probably won't want to answer yet, but it's worth a shot. Rot13(Vf gur qvivfvba bs gur yvarf [guerr-guerr-sbhe-sbhe-gjb-guerr-gjb-guerr-bar-sbhe-sbhe-sbhe-sbhe-gjb] vzcbegnag va gur chmmyr?)

Comment: Great Valentine's Day ramble!  "... play on familiar acts ..."

Comment: From hint level 1: rot13(Vs lbh pbhag juvpu vf gur jbeq ybir sebz gur ortvavat bs gur fragrapr, lbh trg gur frdhrapr: 2, 6, 5, 8, ?, 8, ?, 8, 7, 3, 2, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 9, 7, 8, 8, 4, 7, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9, 3, 9, 8, 3, 3, 2, 6, 8, 6, 3, 8, 9, 3, 3). Maybe?

Comment: @Annosz You're missing one value (see the answers so far). Otherwise, this is a very good observation...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I earlier pointed out in a comment, that according to Hint 1

> We can count the position of the word 'love' in each quote

@Rubio confirmed, that it is a good lead, and now with Hint 2 and Hint 3 we can get the solution.

> The title also contains a 'love', so our numbers are the following: 7 2 6 5 8 0 8 0 8 9 3 2 8 6 6 5 7 6 6 9 7 8 8 4 7 3 7 8 6 9 3 9 8 3 3 2 6 8 6 5 8 9 3 3. (0 where there is no 'love' in the quote)
>  The last song in Hint 3 continues like this: "when two become one", so we couple these numbers into: 72 65 80 80 89 32 86 65 76 69 78 84 73 78 69 39 83 32 68 65 89 33
> Now we got an ASCII text, which can be converted into the following: HAPPY VALENTINE'S DAY!

Comment: Well done! I had that same first string but didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: Nicely done, congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

As @Omega pointed out, there are $42$ occurrences of the word "love".

> From the Hitchhiker's Guide we know that $42$ is the meaning of life. Could the answer then be the "Life Force"?

Comment: The answer is explicitly spelled out in the puzzle. This is not it, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Very Partial:

from Hint with helpfulness 1:

> there are in total 42 'love's in the quotes (including the one in "What force is more potent than love?")

Dunno what to do next...

Comment: With hint 2, we have 42... I guess the answer to life, the universe and everything is stronger than love ¯\_(ツ)_/¯